# What are the most frequent ways someone's password "leaks"?

Tags: passwords, account-security

List of user:hash published? Same password for web and local (os...)? 
Phishing?

Comment: What do you mean by "leaks"? I would not consider phishing a method to "leak" passwords.

Comment: And how do you define "frequent"? Do you mean for all users globally as a set? Do you mean an average individual?

Comment: Phishing campaigns may finish in a leak, and I mean, for a given lambda user

Comment: Ah, then you really need to define your terms. Unauthorised disclosure vs publication. Which do you mean?

Comment: Both, any time it goes public

Comment: And you equate hashes with the plaintext password? And you want to know the most frequent cause of a password or hash being disclosed or exposed without authorisation?

Comment: Unsalted MD5 hashes (lookin' at you, LinkedIn)

Comment: Unsalted or with salt data aside (so any time cracking might be done by a random guy).

Comment: And I was meaning in a users life

Answer (score 1):

Phishing, dictionary and social engineering based approaches are far more frequent than database leaks.

Database leaks result in far more passwords being released than via the above approaches because a large scale leak can result in hundreds of millions of passwords being released.

However - why are you asking? For example if concerned about your own credentials assuming secure practices are used by the service a user can protect themselves from database leaks and dictionary attacks by using a secure unique password. I.e. your username, hash pair can leak without the underlying password being revealed. Sophisticated phishing and social engineering can be harder to protect against at the individual level.

Comment: I debate your assertions. I think an average user's password has been exposed more often through database leaks than through 1:1 credential guessing or harvesting.

Comment: If you count all the password database leaks that are known then add 10% (for unknowns), then that number is greater than the number of times an average person has had their credentials stolen through infection of personal devices, soceng, or bruting.

Comment: But the whole thing is debatable, which is why my finger has been poised over the VTC button, waiting for the OP to answer my last question.

Comment: @schroeder - I'll agree dictionary attacks are statistically ignorable. But phishing attacks are beyond commonplace and a lot of users fall for them (and according to talks from security companies 50% of phishing victims have fallen for phishing scams at least twice). On company devices in a relatively small firm we've had multiple people fall for fake apple emails in the last year. We also see frequent social engineering attempts against the higher net value organization members.

Comment: and I'm with you there, and yet, I think that number is still lower than db leaks

Comment: @schroeder - http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-many-people-fall-victim-to-phishing-attacks/ - 1 in 200 bank’s customers per year. And this is before we consider apple, dropbox, gmail, linkedin etc. Are you suggesting there is a unique database leak for every 200 people?

Comment: @schroeder - saying this maybe there has been a misunderstanding. By "Database leaks result in far more passwords being released than via the above approaches" I mean that more passwords become compromised because of database leaks. My answer attempted to handle both questions (most frequent method vs most frequent cause of leak) since OPs question was ambiguous.

Comment: I'm flipping the stats to be per lambda user. A user has X number of phishable accounts, with a subset of those that a user will potentially succumb to. That number is less than the number of db leaks.

Comment: @schroeder - I don't think I agree (although admit its arguable - hence "think"). If you take X number of accounts then you need to consider most db leaks do not impact all users - so a DB leak becomes a probability function. Meanwhile phished credentials are guaranteed to be valid for at least one service and via credential reuse or SSO may be valid for multiple. A hashed password in a DB leak is not guaranteed to be reversible - see the low rate on bcrypt passwords on https://hashes.org/leaks.php.